# JOGL - Swing - JavaFX

Tags: swing, javafx, jogl

Ok,

I have a working JOGL application. I use a lot of OpenGL features in it including Textures, VBO's, Ray-Picking, etc. I like working with OpenGL directly and don't want to use any other 3D graphics libraries.

What I want to achieve is two fold:

1. I want to be able to embed this JOGL application in a subset window of a larger UI window. So alongside the JOGL window will be a photo viewer, text box and scrollable list.
2. I am designing this application to run on Windows 10, multi touch hardware.

What I have found so far:

1. Java's Swing toolkit is the only way that I have been able to embed a JOGL window. However, Swing is old and dated looking.
2. Incorporating multi touch into swing can be done but does require a lot of custom gesture detection. This is fine but maybe options exists that don't reinvent the wheel.
3. JavaFX looks great and i'd like to use it but I don't see any straightforward way of pairing it with JOGL.

Do any of you have suggestions? Has anyone done this before?

Comment: I don't know if it fits your 1st fold, but did you try [`newt`](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/NEWT-Overview.html)?

Comment: @elect NEWT supports multi touch only under some platforms, under Android for sure.

Comment: Hmmmm. Going to look into this. Never heard of NEWT. Seems like a good option for performance. Currently I am using Swing's GLJPanel

Answer (score 3):

You can integrate JOGL into a JavaFX application by using the SwingNode.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html
The opposite (integrating some JavaFX into a Swing application) is also possible but I would not reccomend it.

Doing the JOGL integration this way will not be as performant as a native OpenGL window but for many application it will be sufficient.

Comment: It's the most trivial approach. I advise you to look at this bug report: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=607 I've tried to sum up all our attempts to support some kind of interoperability between OpenJFX/JavaFX and JOGL. There are some subtle things to keep in mind when packaging an application using them both especially if you don't use Java 1.9.

Comment: @mipa - Ya, i've started to look into this. It seems that no whether you use Swing or JavaFX you aren't going to get performance like native OpenGL. Both have some levels of abstraction. Right now I am using GLJPanel which is quite fast. I'll research more and revert here.

Answer (score 1):

There's a far better solution right now based on JOGL 2.4 RC [NewtCanvasJFX](https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/newt/javafx/NewtCanvasJFX.html), please have a look at [my detailed tutorial](https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2020/04/05/javafx-et-jogl-fonctionnent-ensemble-javafx-and-jogl-work-together/).